# Does the properties of the module $M$ remain invariants when limiting us on the subring only?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\mathbb Z_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers and consider the ring of power series $R=\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ with unique maximal ideal $(p,x)$.

Let $S$ be the subset of of all power series in $R$ without constant term. If I am correct, then $S$ will be a subring.

So if $M$ be a $R$-module, then $M$ will be still a module (or submodule) over the subring $S$.

> Does the properties of the module $M$ remain invariants when limiting us on the subring only ?

For example, if $M$ is free/projective/flat/finite over $R$, would it be same over $S$ ?

Comment: $S$ will not have an identity, thus you have to speak about properties of a module over a non-unital ring, which honestly i have never seen before

Comment: @AlekseiKubanov, thank you very much for clarifying the situation